# How to format Google Adsense adc?

Tags: css, wordpress, adsense

Any idea how this guy formatted the Google Adsense showing on his website? The Adsense Plug-in doesn't allow for formatting, creating on Adsense website neither. As you see he added a left border only and other stylish on colors and fonts, maybe some of you know the trick?

Website: http://www.stopdepressione.it/

Comment: That appears to be part of the ad, not something the website owner added.

Comment: @APAD1 it is from Adsense by Google

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm saying. They didn't format the ad, the border and font styling are part of the actual ad.